# Was it ever shown what the signal was from in Stargate: Universe?

Tags: stargate, stargate-universe

They were looking for the origin of a signal that had an intelligent structure to it. Was it ever shown what the signal actually was and/or who it was sent by? If not, have there been any good assumptions?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, it was never shown. SG Universe was canceled and ended in a cliffhanger episode. To the best of my knowledge the plot was also never resolved in other media. But I could have just missed it.

I remember talk about DVD movies like the ones made for SG-1 but I think nothing ever came of it.
Which I find pretty sad because I really liked the show and I don't understand why ratings were so bad.

As far as assumptions go, I don't think they ever revealed enough clues to actually make one.

Comment: That's unfortunate. I too am quite unsure why the ratings were bad and it was canceled. I loved that show (as well as the other stargates).

Comment: The reason why there are no DVD movies is that there is no DVD market anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about what the Destiny and the entire Ancients exploration program was about? The signal discovered in the left over radiation of the Big Bang that shows that the SG continuum was designed by some other being? No, that was a big reveal of the "the true purpose" of the Ancients program.